# Track Browser Journey or Path - Chrome History View

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to track my browser path to analyze my approach when I'm looking to solve a specific  problem.  Moreover, I'm looking at how I can get a visual tree view of my browser history.  Similair to a Git Commit History where when I have 1 Tab open and I click on a link, I 'branch' into two tabs or something like:

[image]

I've looked at numerous chrome extensions like Visual History, Histree, My Map Free but none of them give a view that I find helpful nor can I export it.

My question:

1. Has anyone done something similar?  Or use an extension that can capture these views?
2. Has anyone scripted a python package and if so, what are some high level details. (I'm familiar with Selenium and plotly but it just seems like overkill at this point - but maybe I need to bite the bullet.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as I know Chrome keeps some information in files `sqlite` and you can read them with Python module `sqlite3`. I think It may keep history also in `sqlite` but I don't know if it has information about connections between pages.

Comment: if you want to create `chrome extension` then you will have to do it with `JavaScript`